# How to load menu on login in Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm facing a problem where I want to add a condition wherein I need to hide some of the buttons in the menu depending on the user who is logged in.  This is easy just a simple if-else statement. My problem here is the menu loads first.  I want to load the menu after I logged in. How do I do this? 
Here's my code:

```
Code inside controller of my menu.
if (Apprsal.userSelectedData().usertype == undefined || Apprsal.userSelectedData().usertype == '')
{
    $scope.nseMenu = true;  //this is just an ng-hide in my menu
    $scope.vaMenu = false;  //this is just an ng-hide in my menu
}
else
{
    $scope.nseMenu = false;
    $scope.vaMenu = true;
}


Code of my config inside app.js
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider

.state('app.home', {
        cache: false,
        url: '/home',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'
            }
        }
    })

.state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    cache: false,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
})
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
});
```

EDIT:

```
Code for my menu.html
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
<ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">

        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
            </button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-side-menu-content>

<ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title"></h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content>
        <div class="item-input-inset search-bar">
        <div class="item-input-wrapper white">
            <input id="searchKey" type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="data.searchKey" autocorrect="off" />


            <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="search(data.searchKey)"><i class="ion-ios7-search ion-search"></i></button>

        </div>

    </div>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/home">
                Home
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/testprofile" ng-hide="vaMenu">
                My Profile
            </ion-item>
            <!-- For NSE only -->
            <a href="#/app/profiles" id="btnProfiles" ng-hide="nseMenu">
            <ion-item menu-close>
                Profiles
            </ion-item>
            </a>
             <!-- end -->
             <!-- For Phase 2
            <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/notify">
                Notifications
            </ion-item>
            -->
            <a href="#">
            <ion-item menu-close ng-click="btnLogout()">
                Logout
            </ion-item>
            </a>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>
```

Comment: Can you add the code for your menu html as well?

Comment: added html @BalaAbhinav

Comment: @JCBorlagdan have you get any solution to this , it will be very kind if you share your solution ,cause i'm facing same problem

Comment: @ramashishtomar i'm no longer working on the project, but the best solution for this is to create a callback function wherein the callback will be executed right after the asynchronous function completes the transaction check this out https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am also new to Ionic but i have implemented a login. In my case i made the abstract view to the menu also but the fallback view as a new login page. And on that page i disabled the side menu. So i can suggest that you can handle it in the following way.

First make a separate login view.

Disable the side menu on that view.
After successful  login move to the home page and then override the scope array which is responsible for showing the list in the side menu according to the permission of the user. Hence you can restrict some feature for particular set of users.
Thank You!

Comment: Hi, my menu is disabled on login page, and yes of course login view is separated from the menu coz it won't be in mvc if i didn't.

Comment: @JC, As i can see that you have not used ng-repeat over an array to fill the menu list. That's why it may be a bit complicated to hide or show a particular menu in the list. 
I suggest use a scope array from the controller and then  loop through ng-repeat. This will give you power to reset the the element of the scope array conditionally

Comment: even if I place an ng-repeat it won't change the condition inside the if, so what's the point?

Comment: do not use. ng-if. Suppose you an array of menu items as $scope.arr = [{'title':'Home', 'href':'#/app/home'},{'title':'Page1', 'href':'#/app/Page1'},{'title':'Page2', 'href':'#/app/page2'}]. And you can conditionally remove one item from the scope array. hence it will be not found by the ng-repeat and hence will not be shown

Comment: and it's easy to remove, but still the condition, won't hit again

Comment: It would, after login. just broadcast an event with the permission of user and receive that event in the menu controller and then reset the scope array.

Comment: okay so let me rephrase the question now, why does my menu loads first before my login?

Comment: What do you mean by My menu loads first before my menu?

Comment: If you go through the ionic page structure you would find that the side menu (abstract view) container div is before the other view pages. Hence it loads first.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use event messaging between you controllers. (i.e)., You can create custom events & pass event objects from one controller to another. This in angular, is achieved by $scope.$on , $scope.$broadcast() & $scope.$emit().
You can go through the last few sections of this [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) to acheive this. Here is another [article](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/angularjs/understanding-emit-broadcast-and-on-in-angularjs) which can help you to do the same.